# QT: Dynamic child button not visible

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a project that I want to add button dynamically wherever I click in my form.

This is my header:

```
namespace Ui {
class frmBedBook;
}

class frmBedBook : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit frmBedBook(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    ~frmBedBook();

private:
    Ui::frmBedBook *ui;
    QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
    QList<QPushButton*> buttonList;
    QGridLayout *lyWidget;
    QWidget *m_widget;
public slots:
    void clicked(int buttonId);
};
```

And this is my implementation:

```
frmBedBook::frmBedBook(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmBedBook)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper();

    QPushButton *p;

    lyWidget = new QGridLayout();

    m_widget = new QWidget();
    m_widget->setGeometry(0,0,930,472);

    lyWidget->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    lyWidget->addWidget(m_widget);
    setLayout(lyWidget);

    p = new QPushButton(m_widget);
    p->setText("00");
    p->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 50);
    buttonList.append(p);
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(p,0);

    p = new QPushButton(m_widget);
    p->setText("01");
    p->setGeometry(50, 0, 50, 50);
    p->setObjectName("01");
    buttonList.append(p);
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(p,1);

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this, SLOT(clicked(int)));
}

void frmBedBook::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPushButton *p;

    p = new QPushButton(m_widget);
    p->setText("02");
    p->setGeometry(QCursor::pos().x(), QCursor::pos().y(), 50, 50);
    buttonList.append(p);
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(p,2);
}
```

The problem is the button is created, but not visible. I know it because I have traced through m_widget's children and it's found. I also already resetting layout in MousePressEvent function, but nothing happened. Could anyone please help me about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `show()` on your buttons if they are added after the form has been constructed. Also, `QCursor::pos()` will probably not deliver the position you want to have.

You can use the `x()/y()` functions of the `QMouseEvent` instead:

```
void frmBedBook::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPushButton *p;

    p = new QPushButton(m_widget);
    p->setText("02");
    p->setGeometry(event->x(), event->y(), 50, 50);
    p->show();
    buttonList.append(p);
    connect(p, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(p,2);
}
```

Note that you need to `#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>` unless you already have that.

Answer (score 1):

You never show the buttons, so they stay hidden. Use `QWidget::show()`. This applies to widgets created in `mousePressEvent`, *after* parent is already shown. The button created in constructor should get automatically shown when its parent is shown.